# Exposing React Components using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

So I am trying to expose all my React components in the bundle to global of the browser (`window`). I am using the webpack's `expose-loader` to do so.

I have full success in exposing plain JS modules but when I try to expose JSX modules, it gives me an error:

```
Module parse failed: ~/project/src/components/list.jsx Line 20: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
...
```

The error only shows up for the 3rd loader entry that uses `expose`. If that loaders entry is removed, React components build just fine.

Here's the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/components/index.js",

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/web"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015"],
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve("react"),
        loader: "expose?React"
      },
      {
        test: /list.jsx$/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015", "expose?List"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I have tried to use `babel-loader` before the `expose` loader to try to fix the error but no luck, same error. Has anyone had any success exposing React components globally using web pack before.

Comment: Is the react preset defined in .babelrc?

Comment: @arve0 Yes, both `es2015` and `react`presets.

Comment: @arve0 Presets are in this order: `es2015` and then `react`.

Comment: @arve0 Same error. BTW, React components build just fine, the error shows up only when I use `expose`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100542/discussion-between-nayaab-and-arve0).

Comment: Sorry, time for work.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `List.jsx`?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I was able to figure it. As @arve0 pointed out in comments, the loaders should be in reverse order. So this works correct:

```
  {
    test: /list.jsx$/,
    loaders: ["expose?List" "babel-loader"]
  }
```

However, order of presets is not significant, at least in this case.

Comment: Also, better to include your presets in a `.babelrc` file since their not really webpack-related config.

Comment: Hey @loganfsmyth, yep I use `.babelrc`. Inlined presets here just for the brevity of code. Avoiding to add another code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The character `<` indicate that jsx is not transformed. Check .babelrc, it should use react preset before any other transforms.

Comment: Switching the order and making `react` first doesn't help with the error. FWIW, without the `expose` all works fine, just that can't make it work with `expose`.

Comment: Shouldn't loaders be in reverse order? Sass is `style!css!sass`.